# TASM Stepper Motor control

Tags: assembly, bios, tasm, dosbox

Im trying to move the stepper motor forward by using my LED running animation code TASM

`.model small
.stack
.code
org 100h
start:
    main proc
    mov cx,1; how many times to loop
    here:mov al,00000001b
    mov dx,378h
    out dx,al
    call delay
    mov al,00000010b
    mov dx,378h
    out dx,al
    call delay
    mov al,00000100b
    mov dx,378h
    out dx,al
    call delay
    mov al,00001000b
    mov dx,378h
    out dx,al
    call delay
    loop here
    int 20h
    main endp
    delay proc
        push cx
        mov cx,2050
        delay2:
        push cx
        mov cx,10000
        delay3:
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        loop delay3
        pop cx
        loop delay2
        pop ax
        ret
    delay endp
end start`

this is my code for running light does anyone knows how to control the stepper motor using tasm through parallel port ?

Comment: i need a code or reference to my stepper motor using tasm assembly language

Comment: the programming language has nothing to do with a stepper motor.  what motor (might not matter)?  what driver?  how is it hooked up?  what protocol if any?

Comment: i have a unipolar motor and hooked up at the breadboard using parallel port my Prof. said that the motor can be move forward/backward with tasm codes

Comment: You have asked this in a few different places.  Try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59296543/12381289) on one of they other questions you asked.